# Confusion with usage of density function.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I'm trying to solve an exercise and im starting to get very confused of my usage of the density function. Can someone explain my where my error is?
I have the two coordinates $X_1,X_2$ that are uniformly distributed on the disk $D=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_1^2+x_2^2<1\}$. At first I want to calculate the density function of $(X_1,X_2)$, lets call it $f$. We know it has to be constant and the integral of $f$ over $D$ has to equal $1$. So by $$\int_Df(x_1,x_2)d(x_1,x_2)=1$$ we know that the density function has to equal $1/\pi$. But now I want to calculate the c.d.f. of $R^2=X_1^2+X_2^2$. So let $g$ be density function of $R^2$. But then I think I use the definition of density function wrong. Because if I calculate the following I get a contradiction.\begin{align*}1=\mathbb{P}=(R^2\leq1)&=\int_0^1g(r)dr\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(\sqrt{r-s},\sqrt{s})dsdr\\&=1/\pi\int_0^1\int_0^11dsdr=1/\pi.\end{align*} My thought process was, that for $R^2=r$ to hold true, we can just "sum up" over all $s\in[0,1]$ with $X_1^2=r-s,X_2^2=s$. But there is obviously a logical error. Can sombody tell me where exactly my fault is and what the right approach to calculate the c.d.f. of $R^2$ is? By logical arguments I know it's $\mathbb{P}(R^2\leq r) = r$, but I'd like to calculate it with the integrals.

Comment: Your bounds are for a unit square. It should rather be, $ \frac{1}{\pi} \displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \int_{- \sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} 1 ~ ds ~ dr$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $Q=R^2$, then for $0 \le r \le 1$ you have

$$\mathbb P(R^2 \le r) =\mathbb P(Q \le r) = \int_{x_2=-\sqrt{r}}^{\sqrt{r}}\int_{x_1=-\sqrt{r-x_2^2}}^{\sqrt{r-x_2^2}} \frac{1}{\pi}\, dx_1\, dx_2 =\int_{x_2=-\sqrt{r}}^{\sqrt{r}}\frac{2 \sqrt{r-{{x_2^2}}}}{\pi }\, dx_2  =r$$ as expected. It gives $1$ when $r=1$, as it should.

The corresponding pdf for $Q$ will be $1$ as this is uniform on $[0,1]$, while the pdf for R will be $\frac d{dx} x^2=2x$ also on $[0,1]$